How to create a step builder in Kotlin that supports repeatable steps
I am investigationg step builder patterns in Kotlin and have a requirement where some of the steps are repeatable or loop able as follows:-
I have a Map<Header, List<Item>> and would like to support the following use cases
Steps
1). User has to add a header first
2). User has to add atleast one item which will added to the current headers list
3.a). the user can now choose to build the map and this is a terminal step.
3.b). the user can choose to add another header and item(s) e.g. repeat steps 1).& 2).
is it possible to implement this in a kotlin step builder pattern?
Valid Examples:-
One Header with Items
val singleHeaderWithItems : Map<Header, List<Item>> = builder()
.withHeader(HeaderOne())
.withItems(HeaderOneItems())
.build()

Multiple Headers with Items
val multipleHeadersWithItems : Map<Header, List<Item>> = builder()
.withHeader(HeaderOne())
.withItems(HeaderOneItems())
.withHeader(HeaderTwo())
.withItems(HeaderTwoItems())
.withHeader(HeaderThree())
.withItems(HeaderThreeItems())
.build()

Invalid Examples:-
Items with no header
val itemsNoHeaderCompileError : Map<Header, List<Item>> = builder()
.withItems(InvalidItems()) // compile error here missing header
.build()

Header with no items
val headerNoItems : Map<Header, List<Item>> = builder()
.withHeader(InvalidHeader()) 
.build()// compile error here missing items


I think DSL style builders (aka type-safe builders) is more suitable for this, and is more idiomatic.
The main problem is, how to enforce the "at least one header and at least one item in each header" rule. One way to do this is to force the builder blocks to all return a "token" that can only be received by calling the method that builds a header/item at the end of the lambda.
data class Header(val name: String)
data class Item(val name: String)

@DslMarker
annotation class HeadersBuilderMarker

@HeadersBuilderMarker
class HeaderBuilderScope {
    sealed interface HasHeader
    private data object HeaderProof : HasHeader

    val headers = mutableMapOf<Header, List<Item>>()

    // by making this block return a ItemBuilderScope.HasItem,
    // we make sure that the caller has called ItemBuilderScope.item at least once
    fun header(name: String, block: ItemBuilderScope.() -> ItemBuilderScope.HasItem): HasHeader {
        headers[Header(name)] = ItemBuilderScope().apply { block() }.items
        return HeaderProof
    }
}

@HeadersBuilderMarker
class ItemBuilderScope {

    sealed interface HasItem
    private data object ItemProof : HasItem

    val items = mutableListOf<Item>()

    fun item(name: String): HasItem {
        items.add(Item(name))
        return ItemProof
    }
}

// by making this block return a HeaderBuilderScope.HasHeader,
// we make sure that the caller has called HeaderBuilderScope.header at least once
fun headersBuilder(block: HeaderBuilderScope.() -> HeaderBuilderScope.HasHeader) =
    HeaderBuilderScope().apply { block() }.headers

Usage:
val headers = headersBuilder {
    header("Foo") {
        item("item 1")
        item("item 2")
    }
    header("Bar") {
        item("item 3")
    }
}

Note that in the same package, users can implement a sealed interface with their own implementation, and hence break this design, so make sure to put the XXXBuilderScopes in a separate package.

Would recommend adding dsl marker interface to builder scopes so it's not possible to nest header(){} calls.

@Pawel Good point. I have edited.

Sure you can: you just need to carefully choose interfaces and classes that have the behaviour you want.
Try this (with playground):
data class Header(val title: String)
data class Item(val name: String)

interface MapBuilderAcceptingHeader {
    fun withHeader(header: Header): MapBuilderAcceptingItem
}

interface MapBuilderAcceptingItem {
    fun withItems(vararg items: Item): BuildableMapBuilder
}

class MapBuilderRequiringHeader : MapBuilderAcceptingHeader {
    override fun withHeader(header: Header): MapBuilderAcceptingItem {
        return MapBuilderRequiringItem(emptyMap(), header)
    }
}

class MapBuilderRequiringItem(
    private val map: Map<Header, List<Item>>, private val header: Header
) : MapBuilderAcceptingItem {
    override fun withItems(vararg items: Item): BuildableMapBuilder {
        return BuildableMapBuilder(map = map, header = header, itemsSoFar = items.toList())
    }
}

class BuildableMapBuilder(
    private val map: Map<Header, List<Item>>,
    private val header: Header,
    private val itemsSoFar: List<Item>
) : MapBuilderAcceptingHeader, MapBuilderAcceptingItem {
    override fun withHeader(header: Header): MapBuilderAcceptingItem {
        return MapBuilderRequiringItem(
            map = build(), header = header
        )
    }

    override fun withItems(vararg items: Item): BuildableMapBuilder {
        return BuildableMapBuilder(
            map = map,
            header = header,
            itemsSoFar = buildList { addAll(itemsSoFar); addAll(items) }
        )
    }

    fun build(): Map<Header, List<Item>> {
        return buildMap { putAll(map); put(header, itemsSoFar) }
    }
}

fun hectorsMapBuilder() : MapBuilderRequiringHeader {
    return MapBuilderRequiringHeader()
}

fun main() {
    val hectorsMap = hectorsMapBuilder()
        // .withItems() does not compile as need at least one header
        // .build() does not compile as need at least one header and one item
        .withHeader(Header("headerOne"))
        // .withHeader() does not compile as need at least one item
        // .build() does not compile  as need at least one item
        .withItems(Item("itemOne"))
        .withHeader(Header("headerTwo"))
        // .build() does not compile as need at least one item
        .withItems(Item("itemTwo"))
        .withItems(Item("itemThree"), Item("itemFour"))
        .build()
    println(hectorsMap) // prints {Header(title=headerOne)=[Item(name=itemOne)], Header(title=headerTwo)=[Item(name=itemTwo), Item(name=itemThree), Item(name=itemFour)]}
}

